# Get date from self object

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am attempting to pull the date field from the current item. I can't seem to get the syntax right. How would I go about getting the date data from the form I just submitted? Whenever I try the code below I get the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**views.py**

```
class EntryCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = EntryForm
    template_name = 'argent/entry_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        e_item = self.object.get()
        e_date = e_item.get('date')
        e_month = e_date.strftime('%B')
        e_year = e_date.year
        qs = MonthYear.objects.filter(month=e_month, year=e_year)
```

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
    euros = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=900, blank=True, null=True)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the models values without using `get()`?  Something instead like `e_item = self.object` followed by `e_date = e_item.date`?  I believe the `get()` method is used for dictionaries and doesn't hold the same meaning as it would a getter in Java for instance.

Comment: The item posts and saves in the db, however, it still errors:  `'NoneType' object is not callable`. For some reason I can't pull the data from the object I just submitted. When I print `e_item.date` for example, I get `None`.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your original question, yes, I have tried without using `get()`. That's when I get the `NoneType' object is not callable` error. I cant seem to pull any data from the submitted item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

So the trick to pulling data from an item immediately after it is submitted is to first save the form.

```
class EntryCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = EntryForm
    template_name = 'argent/entry_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        item = form.save()
        item_date = item.date
        e_month_d = item_date.strftime('%m')
        e_month = item_date.strftime('%B')
        e_year = item_date.year
```

After saving the form the data within the form becomes available for manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `self.object.date`.

I found this: [Django Docs: Form Handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example). The example here accesses the primary key by using `self.object.pk`

Here's an example of what I had done for one of my projects, but note that this was using Django-Rest-Framework so I'm not sure if this would work for you.

**serializers.py**

```
class JournalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Journal
        exclude = ('id', 'user',)

    def get_date(self, obj):
        return obj.date.replace(microsecond=0)
```